# If $f \in C_c^\infty((0,T);H^1(\Gamma))$ is $|f(x,t)| \leq C$ for all $x$ and $t$?

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

Here $\Gamma$ is a bounded closed $C^k$ hypersurface.

If $f \in C_c^\infty((0,T);H^1(\Gamma))$ is $f$ uniformly bounded on $[0,T]\times \Gamma$? Or even does it hold that $|f(t)| \leq C_t$ for constant depending on $t$?

I know that $\lVert f(t) \rVert_{H^1(\Gamma)}$ is uniformly bounded. But not sure about $f$ itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, because an $H^1$ function need not be bounded. For example,  $\phi(x)=\sqrt{-\ln|x|}$ is an unbounded $H^1$ function   in two dimensions; in dimensions above two one has the simpler example $\phi(x)=|x|^{-1/3}$. If $\Gamma$ contains $0$ and $f(t)=\phi\, \eta(t)$, where $\eta$ is a smooth compactly supported function on $(0,T)$, then $f$ satisfies the given assumptions without being pointwise bounded.